# Inaccurate timings when timer is set in separate function

Tags: python, loops, timer

I am having an issue getting my timers to work reliably. I essentially have a loop that is set to call functions as close to the scheduled time as possible. The timings are accurate enough except for the very first tick. For some reason, when setting `last_time` (I've also tried time.time(), time.process_time()) outside the fixed update, (in this example the `start_counting` method), it is not accurate.

When running the code below you will get something like this:

```
---start---
Time since last 1.5854037 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5996268 Time accrued by step: 1.6
---start---
Time since last 1.5247734999999998 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997646000000003 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997717000000007 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5998178999999997 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997903000000004 Time accrued by step: 1.6
```

As you can see the very first iteration from when I start the counter, to the first tick, the timing is way off. However, every tick after that is as accurate as I expected 1.599~, while the initial can be anywhere from 1.52 to 1.58 What exactly am I missing here? The timing should be the same since the steps are the same from start to step reset. I feel like I'm missing something, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Here is my code, runnable as Python 3.7. Tested with 3.6 as well..

```
import time
from collections import deque

class FixedStepLoop:
    def __init__(self, update_func, step, max_step):
        self.update_func = update_func
        self.step = step
        self.max_step = max_step
        self.accumulator = 0.0
        self.next_ts = time.perf_counter()
        self.last_ts = None
        self.cumulative_time = 0
        self.times = deque()
        
    def update_time(self):
        ts = time.perf_counter()
        if self.last_ts is None:
            delta_t = 0
        else:
            delta_t = ts - self.last_ts
            self.times.appendleft(delta_t)
            if len(self.times) > 10:
                self.cumulative_time -= self.times.pop()
        self.cumulative_time += delta_t
        self.last_ts = ts
        return delta_t
        
    def tick(self):
        dt = self.update_time()
        
        if dt > self.max_step:
            dt = self.max_step

        self.accumulator += dt

        while self.accumulator >= self.step:
            self.update_func(self.step)
            self.accumulator -= self.step

tick_count = 16

class FixedCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.steps = None
        self.last_time = time.perf_counter()
        self.counting = False
        self.loop = FixedStepLoop(self.fixed_update, 1/10, 0.2)
        
    def start_counting(self):
        print("---start---")
        self.steps = 0
        self.last_time = time.perf_counter()
        
    def fixed_update(self, dt):
        if self.steps is not None:
            self.steps += 1
            
            if self.steps == tick_count:
                print("Time since last", time.perf_counter() - self.last_time, "Time accrued by step:", self.steps * 0.1)
                self.last_time = time.perf_counter()
                self.steps = 0
    
fixed_counter = FixedCounter()

i = 0
while True:
    fixed_counter.loop.tick()

    i += 1
    
    if i == 8000:
        fixed_counter.start_counting()
        
    if i == 2000000:
        fixed_counter.start_counting()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your `fixed_counter.loop` has already accumulated some time towards its next tick by the time you call `fixed_counter.start_counting`.

Hence, the first call from `tick` to `fixed_update` after calling `start_counting` occurs less than a tenth of a second after making that call to `start_counting`. In other words, from the perspective of `fixed_counter`, the first tick can be shorter than the rest.

In fact, the first call from `tick` to `fixed_update` should be expected to occur anywhere from ~0 to 1/10 of a second after the call to `start_counting`. In the best case, the last call to tick *before* calling `start_counting` emptied the accumulator to ~0, and the accumulator will still take about 1/10 of a second to get back to a value greater our 1/10 step size. In the worst case, the accumulator could reach a value greater than (or equal to) 1/10 immediately *after* the call to `start_counting`. In that case, almost no time will have passed before the first call to `fixed_update`.

You can verify that this is what is happening with the modified code below. I have  changed the code so that the call to `start_counting` causes the `tick` function to print the time between the call to `start_counting` and the first `tick` *after* the call to `start_counting`, followed by the times between the next two calls to `tick`.

```py
import time
from collections import deque

class FixedStepLoop:
    def __init__(self, update_func, step, max_step):
        self.update_func = update_func
        self.step = step
        self.max_step = max_step
        self.accumulator = 0.0
        self.next_ts = time.perf_counter()
        self.last_ts = None
        self.cumulative_time = 0
        self.times = deque()
        self.debug_tick = 0
        self.debug_time = None
        
    def update_time(self):
        ts = time.perf_counter()
        if self.last_ts is None:
            delta_t = 0
        else:
            delta_t = ts - self.last_ts
            self.times.appendleft(delta_t)
            if len(self.times) > 10:
                self.cumulative_time -= self.times.pop()
        self.cumulative_time += delta_t
        self.last_ts = ts
        return delta_t
        
    def tick(self):
        dt = self.update_time()
        
        if dt > self.max_step:
            dt = self.max_step

        self.accumulator += dt
        
        if self.accumulator >= self.step and self.debug_tick:
            print("Time to tick: {}".format(time.perf_counter() - self.debug_time))
            self.debug_time = time.perf_counter()
            self.debug_tick -= 1
            

        while self.accumulator >= self.step:
            self.update_func(self.step)
            self.accumulator -= self.step

tick_count = 16

class FixedCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.steps = None
        self.last_time = time.perf_counter()
        self.counting = False
        self.loop = FixedStepLoop(self.fixed_update, 1/10, 0.2)
        
    def start_counting(self):
        print("---start---")
        self.steps = 0
        self.last_time = time.perf_counter()
        self.loop.debug_tick = 3
        self.loop.debug_time = self.last_time
        
    def fixed_update(self, dt):
        if self.steps is not None:
            self.steps += 1
            
            if self.steps == tick_count:
                print("Time since last", time.perf_counter() - self.last_time, "Time accrued by step:", self.steps * 0.1)
                self.last_time = time.perf_counter()
                self.steps = 0
    
fixed_counter = FixedCounter()

i = 0
while True:
    fixed_counter.loop.tick()

    i += 1
    
    if i == 8000:
        fixed_counter.start_counting()
        
    if i == 2000000:
        fixed_counter.start_counting()
```

You should see something like the output below. Notice that the first time to tick is noticeably smaller than the second and third.

```
---start---
Time to tick: 0.08820800000000001
Time to tick: 0.09974270000000002
Time to tick: 0.09983560000000002
Time since last 1.5882072 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997456999999997 Time accrued by step: 1.6
---start---
Time to tick: 0.0507023000000002
Time to tick: 0.09982599999999975
Time to tick: 0.09973420000000033
Time since last 1.5507022999999998 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997678000000004 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997316999999995 Time accrued by step: 1.6
```

---

If you need more precision, you should decrease the `step` and `max_step` you use for your `FixedStepLoop` and increase `tick_count` accordingly. For example, I get the following output by changing `step`, `max_step`, and `tick_count` to `0.01`, `0.02`, and `1600`, respectively.

```
---start---
Time since last 1.5979447999999998 Time accrued by step: 1.6
---start---
Time since last 1.5954332000000004 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997648999999994 Time accrued by step: 1.6
Time since last 1.5997534 Time accrued by step: 1.6
```

Of course, there is still a difference between the first and subsequent times that the message is printed, but you should be able to change the parameters to make the difference arbitrarily low.

Comment: I really appreciate the response. This does make sense on why it does it, however increasing tick count isn't an option. These settings were already slower than what I needed, it was mostly slowed down so my console wouldn't get spammed. However, your idea did lead me to an idea on a workaround. If I schedule `start_counting` to be called directly after the `update_func` then it can get called within the proper accumulation stage. The only downside is of course a delay between calling it and the next fixed tick, however the iterations are small enough to not be a big issue for my use. Thanks